# Getting code versions from svn

Tags: svn, version-control

svn provides the up-to-date version of the code.
Is it possible to get the different versions ( not revisions ) of a project stored in svn ?

UPDATE:
It is not my project, it is a general question for any open source project. I do not know if there is any specific used tags or not.

Comment: svn export -r 16873 is this you need?

Comment: This will export the source code till the REVISION 16873.
I want to export the source code till v2.0.1 for example

Comment: Let's say you have released e.g. 25 different releases with their corresponding version number. What do you want to do exactly? Get a list of what those version numbers are? Export the 25 versions into 25 different folders? And, have you used standard tags or you use something entirely different?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the 25 different versions of the source code into 25 different folders.
It is not my project, it is a general question for any open source project. I do not know if there is any specific used tags or not.

Answer (score 1):

I you have tagged them, `svn co url://path/to/repo/tags/v2_0_1`. If you have not, you will need to find from logs or something which precise revision corresponds to your version. (The `/tags` directory is not a feature of Subversion itself, but this is a common way to arrange things. To `svn`, tags and branches are just copies of individual revisions.)

Of course, in order for this to work, you need to obey some common conventions. A common workflow is to always have exactly three directories in the root of your repo; these are `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags`. You would always create new branches for development work from the head in trunk, merge to trunk when you are done, tag in tags when releasing. The command in each case is simply `svn cp`. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html